# Update thousands of rows in mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, bulkupdate

Im trying to update 50000 rows in my database, the following code should do that but I always get an error :

> Error: connection time out

I've an UPDATE statement which can update more than 50k records. I want to update them in batches of 1000 or 10000. I tried but I am unable to get desired result.

```
$sync_to ='master_trainee';
$connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
$this->clientdb = $clientdb = Yii::$app->get('clientdb');
$command2 = $clientdb->createCommand('SELECT * from psdftrainee WHERE change1 =' 
."'".$sync_label."'".  ' AND synced = 0 LIMIT 100' );
$data2 = $command2->queryALL();
$effected_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if (isset($data2)&& !empty($data2)) {
     $sql1 = array();
     foreach ($data2 as $val) {                      
     $query = 'UPDATE ' .$sync_to. ' SET table_ID         ='. "'".$val['ID']."'". ','
                                    .'TraineeID          =' ."'".$val['TraineeID']."'". ','
                                    .'StatusChangeDate   =' ."'".$val['StatusChangeDate']."'". ','
                                    .'IsDual             =' ."'".$val['IsDual']."'". ','
                                    .'Assessment         =' ."'".$val['Assessment']."'". ','
                                    .'VoucherHolder      =' ."'".$val['VoucherHolder']."'". ','
                                    .'StatusReason       =' ."'".$val['StatusReason']."'". ','
                                    .'changeDate         =' ."'".$val['changeDate']."'". ',' 
                                    .'effected_on        =' ."'".$effected_date."'". 

                                    ' WHERE table_ID     =' . "'".$val['ID']."'".' AND TraineeID=' . "'".$val['TraineeID']."'".' AND ClassID=' . "'".$val['ClassID']."'";

    $commands = $connection->createCommand($query);
    $res = $commands->execute();

    $sql1[] = '('."'".$val['ID']."'".','."'".$val['TraineeID']."'".','."'".$val['ClassID']."'".')';

   }

   $synced = 'UPDATE ' .$sync_from. ' SET synced=1 
   Where (ID,TraineeID,ClassID) IN ('.implode(',', $sql1).')';
   $cmd = $clientdb->createCommand($synced);
   $cmd->execute();

   $message = $sync_to." Table has updated successfuly <br>";
    $msg_status = 1;
}else{
    $message = $sync_to." Table has no data to updation  <br>";
    $msg_status = 0;
}
 echo json_encode(array("message"=>$message, "code"=>$msg_status));<br>
```

I tried a lot of different things nothing worked.

Comment: Before you take another step, please see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Do not use iterative update. Use one `INSERT .. ODKU` query with data array. Ensure that the columns combination which is used for record to update identifying is defined as unique index.

Comment: you have 2 options, 1) increase the php timeout setting, or a better way, 2) is to process your data in batches, **batch operation**.

Comment: Run this command from console - there is no time limits! `php insert_into_db.php`

Comment: Further to Strawberry's comment, a prepared/bound query would allow you to use a single SQL query to update as many rows as you want, as once prepared a query can be executed with different parameters for great performance increase - this will avoid the drawbacks of using a single `INSERT .. ODKU` query, as this can fail if the query is too gargantuan (packet size exceeded errors)

Comment: how can I perform batch operation ?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to walk through the table in the order it is laid out on disk -- by the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Do 1000, not 10K; 10K risks blocking other connections, while not providing much benefit the the `UPDATE`.

Here are the details on chunking:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks